# Command line pub / sub without a server?

Tags: command-line, ipc

Is there a way of implementing the [publish / subscribe pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) from the command line without using a server process? This need only work on one machine.

The main thing I want to avoid by not having a server process is having configure a machine to use these tools. I'm also quite keen on not having to deal with the possibility of my server process dying.|

This might look something like:

```
# client 1
subscribe name | while read line; do echo $line; done

# client 2
subscribe name | while read line; do echo $line; done

# server
echo message | publish name
```

## Related links

- [POSIX ipc](https://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview) provides a serverless *message queue* and there are command-line clients for it [(1)](https://github.com/maandree/cmdipc) [(2)](https://github.com/goeb/mq) [(3)](https://github.com/twinshadow/qtools). This could be used together with some sort of state storage to implement the above.
- [ZMQ](http://zeromq.org/) provides a [protocol for pub / sub communication](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html). There are command-line tools analogous to [nc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) for using *ZMQ*, such as [zmcat](https://github.com/lucasdicioccio/zmcat). These could be used to set up a minimal command-line pub/sub pattern *with a server*.
- Linux provides another IPC mechanism called [named pipes (c.f. mkfifo)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mkfifo). I don't know what the intended behaviour with multiple consumers is. But some initial experimentation suggests that each message is only [received by one of the consumers](https://pastebin.com/raw/EmCnS9BJ)

Comment: Do named pipes do what you want? If not, [edit] to explain why.

Comment: Hmm... as far as I'm aware named pipes only have one consumer, or at least the lines are only received by the earliest connected pipe.

Comment: Hmm, the [O_ASYNC](https://linux.die.net/man/2/open) flag to open might cause data to be sent to all connected processes.

Comment: I don't think this async mode is particularly related. It just seems like a way to "wake up a process" when it should be reading or writing.

Comment: Asking to do this without a "server process" is ambiguous. In this context the kernel is just the server in the case of pipes and "publish" in the pseudo code would result in a server process.

Comment: Maybe. I would note that language as a rule tends to be ambiguous because the world is quite big :P. I think most  people would view using a pipe as quite different in nature from, say, a RabbitMQ server. I guess what I really mean is "without having to setup, manage, configure and monitor a process." I'll update the question to this effect. Things like *dbus* are an interesting middleg-round: always running and (I think?) configuration-free. This does make me depend on X... I think.

Comment: I think what you mean is you don't want to depend on external services. The server in this case is already part of Linux and controlled by your program?

Comment: Umm, that's probably accurate. I want to be able to easily write code using pub/sub patterns in a quick easily modifiable way, which basically means command line tools. If I could just just type "apt-get install IPC" and have a server that was easy to talk to get spawned that would be fine as well. What I don't want to do is tell people using the things I made to *just install postgres and follow this simple 30 step list".  When I've done similar things before I've done the whole "spawn unix domain socket server on first call, send it messages" thing but it's  a lot of code and fragile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All subscribers need to be notified of new data in a way that doesn't affect other subscribers and the server must not have to keep track of what data subscribers have received. This makes FIFO useless for this purpose. Ironically a regular file will do exactly what you want because file descriptors on regular files keep track of file changes. You can combine this with overwrite which ensures all changes are published before a new overwrite occurs meaning you are only storing one message.

```
touch pubsub

tail -f pubsub | while read line; do echo $line; done
tail -f pubsub | while read line; do echo $line; done

echo "message" | cat > pubsub
```

You will get "file truncated" on standard error which is expected behavior but if you don't want to see it add 2> /dev/null

tail is actually doing everything read and echo do but its written like that because I assume you want to incorporate it in a script.

Comment: If you want to do this only in memory I'm pretty sure there's a way. Easiest would be to put pubsub in /run

Comment: That is ingenious and wonderfully hacky!. I guess the only downside to this is the pubsub eventually becomes huge. But this isn't a problem for me. Actually it doubles up as log file :)

Comment: I had a look under the hood and `tail -f` is using `inotify` rather than polling, so updates are "immediate". As an aside, one probably wants a `-n 0` on the tail as well.

Comment: When the -n option is used with -f its basically like a chuck size for lines. Every line is still printed.

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite follow. The reason I wanted `-n 0` is so that when "rejoining" the pubsub stream you don't get the previous 10 messages repeated (https://pastebin.com/CCTpJP8Y)

Comment: Good point about rejoining. Although I wasn't concerned with that considering > will always overwrite.

Comment: Can anyone explain why the `cat` is in fact mandatory there? Without it (e.g. `for i in $(seq 1 10); do echo $(seq 1 $i) > pubsub; sleep 0.1; done`), `tail` behaves erratically and displays only the "deltas" in message; while when `cat` is included (`for i in $(seq 1 10); do echo $(seq 1 $i) | cat > pubsub; done`; notice no sleep was used) all messages arrive perfectly.

Comment: @Yuval This isn't strictly to do with `cat` For example you can just put () around echo and it always works. When ever you do $() thats a subprocess and when you do sleep the process its directed back to is now asleep as seq is executing.